# Use home network for learning browser-server communcation

Tags: javascript, web, networking, browser, webserver

I'm really new to html, css, javascript and all kind of web development. After I coded my first own website, I'd like to play a little with communcation between the browser and a server.

I'd like to be able to access a website hosted on my PC (using my PC as "Web" server) over my home network (my router) so that I can load and use it for example on my smartphone. There's no need for it being accessible over the internet, I only want to use it at home when being connected to my WiFi.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very simply build your own server using [Node.js](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm) and [Express.js](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_overview.htm#:%7E:text=ExpressJS%20is%20a%20web%20application%20framework%20that%20provides,not%20worry%20about%20low%20level%20protocols,%20processes,%20etc.).

Here is a simple snippet to create a server on port 8001 on your PC.

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.listen(8001, () => {
      console.log("Listening on port 8001");
});
```

After that, you start building routes, middleware, and static files for your server. More info can be found [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/261/how-to-create-an-http-server-with-express-in-node-js) and [here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-simple-web-server-using-node-js-and-express/).